# allocating/distributing a certain numerical value factors to aim factor list

Tags: python, r, sampling

I have to allocate a data that has different value factors to each person, and the aim is getting factors in both length and sum balance between each person.
And I have the data like this:

```
set.seed(651700)
num <- 1231
#factor is the case here
caseDf <- data.frame(caseID = as.factor(c(1:num))) 
# each case has a very different amount of value
caseDf$amount <- rnorm(num, mean = rep(c(121,3312,23700),each=13),sd = c(5,213,15000)) 
#each case also is belong to different type
caseDf$type <- factor(sample(c("type_a","type_b","type_c","type_d"),size = num,replace = T,
                                prob = c(0.81,0.05,0.04,0.1))) 
#the all value is above 0
caseDf <- caseDf[caseDf$amount > 0,]
caseDf$amount <- round(caseDf$amount,2)

#staff list, each staff belong to different group
staffDf <- data.frame(staffID = as.factor(c(1:120)))
staffDf$group <- factor(sample(c("group1","group2","group3","group4","group5","group6"),
                               size = 120,replace = T,
                               prob = c(0.3,0.1,0.25,0.15,0.1,0.1)))
```

**aim point:**

- allocate the case to the staff as balance as possible both in length and sum of case,
- try to get the same of the type distribution of case in each staff group or can control the the type distribution of case

I have take try with the function sample(), but it only gets the allotment solution of length. So may I get help to solve the question, the solution in R is better, but in python is also okay.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

After half year, I think I already have the answer for my own question now. This is a value equally allocating/distributing problem. It **equally** allocates a certain numerical values to  aim factor list.

```
#disorder aim factor list to get more random result
staffDf <- staffDf[sample(nrow(staffDf), nrow(staffDf)),]

#arrange the numerical value
caseDf <- arrange(caseDf,desc(amount))

#allocate the numerical value factor to aim factor
caseDf$caseID <- rep(caseDf,times = nrow(caseDf)/length(staffDf), 
length.out = nrow(caseDf))
```